# How do v call the render function of a class from a function of another class in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

How do v call the render function of a class from a function of another class in ReactJS?

```
 var A = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
    //"something" that needs to b executed
    }
    });
    var B = React.createClass({
    funct1 : function(){
    //Place where u need "something" to b executed 
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the component name there, as you would use a tag name inside `render()`. For example, to reference A from B, you just put this in B's `render()`:

```
<A />
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I'll let u know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to access the render function of another class you just include it as a tag in the function and return that.

```
 var A = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
    //"something" that needs to b executed
    }
 });
 var B = React.createClass({
    funct1 : function(){
       return  <A/> ;
    }
 });
```

For example if you want A's `render()` to be in B's `funct1()`. The just `return <A/>` in `funct1()`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: @MihikaMishra Could you accept it as an answer if it solved you problem